use AWS GLUE to execute sql on redshift
I have a set of ETL queries and am trying to create an AWS GLUE job to run against a redshift cluster. I have looked at pre/post actions but that doesn't seem to match my use case as the queries ARE the job, and more complicated than I want to manage in a single line.
My previous ETL experience is with airflow, so I'm a bit confused why glue wants this to be difficult.
The queries:
CREATE TABLE temp_data AS
WITH new_items AS (
  SELECT a, b, max(date) target_date FROM source WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :start - interval '5 minute' GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT ...columns FROM source
JOIN new_items ON conditions;

DELETE FROM source 
USING temp_data
WHERE conditions;

INSERT INTO target (...columns)
SELECT ...columns
FROM temp_data
WHERE condition;

DROP TABLE temp_data;

With airflow this would be very simple. Create a dag with a connection to redshift and execute the query with the :start param. Is there a similar process for GLUE?
Note: we are using Glue instead of airflow for a number of reasons related to the rest of the ETL process
